# Is it possible to drag and drop an entire day (all day events) thorugh fullCalendar in js

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

-I need to drag and drop all the events of the day which here I taken as timetable of the day, when I drag that timetable it should be able to drag all the events in a day and drop into another day which we select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put events into the same group using the `groupId` property (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object), they can be dragged and resized all together in one action.

In the sample data below, all the events with group ID `1` can be dragged as one.

```
events: [
  {
    title: "Sales Meeting",
    start: "2020-04-02 10:30",
    end: "2020-04-02 11:30",
    allDay: false,
    groupId: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Marketing Meeting",
    start: "2020-04-02 11:30",
    end: "2020-04-02 11:30",
    allDay: false,
    groupId: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Production Meeting",
    start: "2020-04-02 15:30",
    end: "2020-04-02 16:30",
    allDay: false,
    groupId: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Management Meeting",
    start: "2020-04-02 13:30",
    end: "2020-04-02 14:30",
    allDay: false,
    groupId: 2,
    color: "green"
  }
]
```

Live Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/bGVbLpr - drag any of the blue-coloured events to the next day, and when you release the mouse you'll see that all the others are also moved with it.

Comment: I am glad to have a response from you. But my scenario is suppose if I have 5 events named Event1,Event2,Event3,Event4,Event5. I need to keep Event1 as constant in such a way that when I drag Event1 all events should be drag and drop. But here with the code you provided even If i drag any event , all the events with same group ID are moving..But for me when I drag Event1 only, then all the events with same groupID should be moved but when i drag remaining events like event2,event3  drag shouldn't occur even though it belong to same group it should be precised to event1 only. Is it possible?

Comment: No that's not possible using fullCalendar's existing features, sorry. You'd have to write your own custom code to control that. Anyway, I answered the question that you asked. You didn't give this extra detail until afterwards. So please can you mark the answer as accepted, as it provides a solution for what you originally requested

Comment: I have already accepted your answer. It's showing like this, Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I think now I'm accepted your answer. Thanks again : )